# SQL: finding values not in a range

Tags: sql, oracle, range, distinct-values

I have a table like this:

| cable_id | total_capacity | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XX1 | 12 | 1 | 5 |
| XX1 | 12 | 7 | 7 |
| XX1 | 12 | 8 | 9 |
| XX1 | 12 | 11 | 12 |

(This is an example for one cable_id, there are millions more)
Using Oracle SQL, I want to create a table for each cable_id containing all the start-end values that are not in the range of the total_capacity.

In my example, 6 and 10 are the start-end missing values from the 1 to 12 range, so the resulting table would be something like that:

| cable_id | missing_number |
| --- | --- |
| XX1 | 6 |
| XX1 | 10 |

I thought about creating another table with cable_id and all the total_capacity range numbers (from 1 to 12) then make an outer join with my first table, but this would probably be very time-consuming (remember there are millions of cables) and Oracle doesn't make it easy to create range of values...

Any help on that would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have overlaps, you can use `lead()` to get the ranges of missing values:

```
select end + 1, next_start - 1
from (select t.*, lead(start) over (order by start) as next_start
      from t
     ) t
where next_start > end + 1;
```